# SwiftUI: Environment Object Publisher doesn't send updates in onReceive

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, environmentobject

I have a Network Monitor from where I want to receive notifications when status has changed.
Looks like this:

```
 final class NetworkMonitor: ObservableObject {
    let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Monitor")

    static let shared = NetworkMonitor()

    @Published var status: NetworkStatus = .connected

    func start() {
        self.monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.status = (path.status == .satisfied) ? .connected : .disconnected
            }
        }

        self.monitor.start(queue: self.queue)
    }
}
```

I create in Home a **@StateObject** of Network monitor and send it by an environment object.

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @StateObject var networkMonitor = NetworkMonitor()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ContentView().environmentObject(networkMonitor)
        }
     }
 }
```

And I want in **ContentView** to receive any changes occur.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var networkMonitor: NetworkMonitor
  var body: some View {
     VStack {
         Text("Example")
     }.onReceive(self.networkMonitor.$status, perform: { status in
            print("onReceive \(status)") // <---- this doesn't trigger
       })
   }
}
```

I can't figure it out why whenever a change occurs in network status, the **onReceive** doesn't trigger.

EDIT: I am using shared instance to start monitoring in AppDelegate.

```
     func application(_: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions _: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        NetworkMonitor.shared.start()
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `start`? Why is there a `shared` property (making it look like a singleton), but then you're creating an instance and passing it via `envrionmentObject`? Are you sure you aren't using `shared` somewhere else and using a different instance than what you have in your view?

Comment: @jnpdx I added an edit for your response.

Comment: Looks like what I suspected in the second half of my comment -- you're using a different instance in your `AppDelegate` than you are in your view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a different instance in your `AppDelegate` (`shared`) than you are in your `HomeView` (`NetworkMonitor()`).

Usually, when you use a singleton pattern, you want to make the `init` private so that you can avoid this mistake:

```
final class NetworkMonitor: ObservableObject {
    let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Monitor")

    static let shared = NetworkMonitor()

    @Published var status: NetworkStatus = .connected

    private init() { } //<-- Here

    func start() {
        self.monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.status = (path.status == .satisfied) ? .connected : .disconnected
            }
        }

        self.monitor.start(queue: self.queue)
    }
}
```

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @StateObject var networkMonitor = NetworkMonitor.shared //<-- Here

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ContentView().environmentObject(networkMonitor)
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: omg I'm so stupid ‍♂️ thank you, you have brightened my day. I'll make this the accepted answear